# Getting a request error 422 upon get request

Tags: python, python-requests

I have seen some posts about this but most of them used requests.post and I want a get request.

I am making a program that simply goes to a url and gets a list of orders.

This is the example response:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "pageCount": 22,
  "orderCount": 214,
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": "c1497823-370c-4c7a-82cd-dacddb36fc30",
      "productId": "1a641ba5-38df-4acb-86f7-f5c031e538a0",
      "email": "demoemail@autobuy.io",
      "ipAddress": "127.0.0.1",
      "total": 18,
      "currency": "USD",
      "gateway": "Stripe",
      "isComplete": true,
      "createdAtUtc": "2019-10-15T01:44:10.5446599+00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": "228f4ca4-5001-4c19-8350-f960f13d35a7",
      "productId": "a0041cc0-2bc6-40a2-9084-5880bae5ecec",
      "email": "demoemail@autobuy.io",
      "ipAddress": "127.0.0.1",
      "total": 50,
      "currency": "USD",
      "gateway": "Stripe",
      "isComplete": true,
      "createdAtUtc": "2019-10-15T01:43:17.8322919+00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": "71aed9b2-4bd2-4a49-9e6a-82119e6e05bf",
      "productId": "2e0ac75b-bfea-42f1-ad60-ead17825162a",
      "email": "demoemail@autobuy.io",
      "ipAddress": "127.0.0.1",
      "total": 6,
      "currency": "USD",
      "gateway": "Stripe",
      "isComplete": true,
      "createdAtUtc": "2019-10-14T23:54:44.6217478+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I get:

`<Response [422]>`

My code:

```
import requests
url = "https://autobuy.io/api/Orders?page=1"

headers = {
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "APIKey": "<APIKEY>"
}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(req)
```

Documentation for the api I'mtrying to use https://api.autobuy.io/?version=latest

edit: on their site it says

```
HEADERS
APIKey
2cdbdc48-b297-41ad-a234-329db0d2dbea

AutoBuy Api Key found in your shop settings
```

but then when I remove my `Cache-Control` and `Pragma` headers I get an error that has to do with my headers being cached (cause the site is behind a CDN?)

Comment: Probably shouldn't post your API key

Comment: Not my API key, it's the one they provide

Answer (score -1):

Ended up being a bug in the site, my dashboard was showing an invalid key.